# Exibir modal ao submeter form. Sem carregar a página

Tags: php, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tenho o código abaixo. Gostaria de exibir um modal assim que submeter o formulário e se todos os campos estiverem preenchidos. Caso algum campo não tenha sido preenchido ele já esta mostrando uma popover no campo indicando que está errado. Agradeço pela contribuição.

```
<form id="form" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="nome_empresa">
                        Nome da empresa
                      </label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da empresa" id="nome_empresa" name="nome_empresa" class="form-control required body" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="repre_empresa">
                        Representante da empresa
                      </label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Representante da Empresa" id="repre_empresa" name="repre_empresa" class="form-control required body" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email_representante">
                        Email do Representante
                      </label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Email do Representante" id="email_representante" name="email_representante" class="form-control required email" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="tel_comercial">
                        Telefone Comercial
                      </label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="99-9999-9999" id="tel_comercial" name="tel_comercial" class="form-control tel_comercial" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="cel_representante">
                        Celular do Representante
                      </label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="99-99999-9999" id="cel_representante" name="cel_representante" class="form-control cel_representante" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="horario_visita">
                        Horário Preferencial da Visita
                      </label>
                      <select name="horario_visita" id="horario_visita" class="form-control required name" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                        <option value="">Escolha o melhor horário</option> 
                        <option value="Manha">Manhã</option> 
                        <option value="Tarde">Tarde</option> 
                        <option value="Noite">Noite</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="num_funcionarios">
                        Número de Funcionários da empresa
                      </label>
                      <select name="num_funcionarios" id="num_funcionarios" class="form-control required name" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                        <option value="">Selecione a quantidade de funcionários</option> 
                        <option value="ZeroACinco">0-5</option> 
                        <option value="CincoADez">5-10</option> 
                        <option value="DezAVinte">10-20</option> 
                        <option value="VinteATrinta">20-30</option>
                        <option value="AcimaDeTrinta">Acima de 30</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="serv_interesse">
                        Serviço de maior interesse
                      </label>
                      <select name="serv_interesse" id="serv_interesse" class="form-control required name" data-placement="right" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Possível erro">
                        <option value="">Escolha a área de maior interesse</option> 
                        <option value="ServicoUm">Serviço 01</option> 
                        <option value="ServicoDois">Serviço 02</option> 
                        <option value="ServicoTres">Serviço 03</option> 
                        <option value="ServicoQuatro">Serviço 04</option>
                        <option value="ServicoCinco">Serviço 05</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="modal-toggle btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal">               
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu adicionaria o atributo `required="required"` em todos os campos.

Para validar no back-end, faria uma verificação ajax. Se houver campos em branco, retornaria o erro em real-time.

Você pode fazer algo em jQuery tbm:

```
$("#campo").blur(function(){
  var valor = $("#campo").val();
  if (valor == null)
    $("#erro").html("Campo xyz obrigatório não preenchido.");
});
```